# How can I code up a LINQ query to check for more than one condition?

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
   var pk = "001";
   if (accounts.Any(b => b.Title.Equals(account.Title)))
```

What I would like to do is to also add a check that b.PartitionKey is not equal to a value I stored in a variable such as the variable pk. Is there a way that I can add this into the b => ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
if (accounts.Any(b => b.Title.Equals(account.Title) && !b.PartitionKey.Equals(pk)))
```